# Error "unreachable statement" al ejecutar programa

Tags: java, array

Al compilar el siguiente programa en el cmd me sale el error:

> unreachable statement

```
public class Ejercicio1{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        //A)
        int[] f = {10,2,4,5,4,3,8,9,2,3};
        System.out.println (f[6]);

        //B)
        float g[];
        g = new float [10];
        g[5]= 5;

        //C)
        int arregloEnteros[];
        arregloEnteros = new int [1001];
        for (int i = 0; 1 <=1000; i++){
            arregloEnteros [i] = 1;
        }
        //D)
        int[] arregloA = new int[10];
        int[] arregloB= new int[20];
        for (int j = 2; j < arregloA.length; j++){
            arregloB[j]=arregloA[j-2];
        }

        //E)
        int[][] matriz = new int[3][3];
        matriz[0][0] = 1;
        matriz[0][2] = 3;
        matriz[0][1] = 2;
        matriz[1][0] = 4;
        matriz[1][1] = 5;
        matriz[1][2] = 6;
        matriz[2][0] = 7;
        matriz[2][1] = 8;
        matriz[2][2] = 9;
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

El error esta en la sección C, ya que este error indica que el parte del código nunca se va a ejecutar:

```
int arregloEnteros[];
arregloEnteros = new int [1001];
for (int i = 0; 1 <=1000; i++){
    arregloEnteros [i] = 1;
}
```

La parte del código que nunca se ejecutaria es `1 <= 1000`, por lo cual deberias de cambiarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
int arregloEnteros[];
arregloEnteros = new int [1001];
for (int i = 0; i <=1000; i++){
    arregloEnteros [i] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El error es debido a la evaluación del ciclo en el *for*, estás considerando `1 <=1000`, lo cual es incorrecto.

```
for (int i = 0; 1 <=1000; i++){
    arregloEnteros[i] = 1;
}
```

Debería ser:

```
for (int i = 0; i <=1000; i++){
    arregloEnteros[i] = 1;
}
```